# SQL error when searching in Android in SearchAction (Action bar)

Tags: android, sql, android-logcat

I'm trying to do a search in the action bar, but when I search nothing is showed and logcat send me an error.

**I have done this:**

```
private boolean mAwaitingUpdate = false;
private ChatViewPagerAdapter nSearchChatViewPagerAdapter = null;
private MyLoaderCallbacks mLoaderCallbacks;

class MyLoaderCallbacks implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

    if (mSearchString != null) {

        buf.append('(');
        buf.append(Imps.Provider.NAME);
        buf.append(" LIKE ");
        android.database.DatabaseUtils.appendValueToSql(buf, "%" + mSearchString + "%");
        buf.append(" OR ");
        buf.append(Imps.Provider.FULLNAME);
        buf.append(" LIKE ");
        android.database.DatabaseUtils.appendValueToSql(buf, "%" + mSearchString + "%");
        buf.append(')');

    }

    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(NewChatActivity.this, Imps.Provider.CONTENT_URI_WITH_ACCOUNT,
            ContactListFragment.PROVIDER_PROJECTION,buf == null ? null : buf.toString(),null ,Imps.Provider.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);


    loader.setUpdateThrottle(50L);

    return loader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor newCursor) {
    nSearchChatViewPagerAdapter.swapCursor(newCursor);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    nSearchChatViewPagerAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}

}

public void doFilterAsync (final String query)
{

        doFilter(query);
}

public synchronized void doFilter(String filterString) {

    mSearchString = filterString;

    if (nSearchChatViewPagerAdapter == null) {

        nSearchChatViewPagerAdapter = new ChatViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mChatPager.setAdapter(nSearchChatViewPagerAdapter);

        mLoaderCallbacks = new MyLoaderCallbacks();
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(CHAT_SEARCH_PAGE_LOADER_ID , null, mLoaderCallbacks);
    } else {

        if (!mAwaitingUpdate)
        {
            mAwaitingUpdate = true;
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable ()
            {

                public void run ()
                {

                    getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(CHAT_SEARCH_PAGE_LOADER_ID , null, mLoaderCallbacks);
                    mAwaitingUpdate = false;
                }
            },1000);
        }

    }
}
```

**The provider projection is:**

```
private static final String[] PROVIDER_PROJECTION = {
                                                         Imps.Provider._ID,
                                                         Imps.Provider.NAME,
                                                         Imps.Provider.FULLNAME,
                                                         Imps.Provider.CATEGORY,
                                                         Imps.Provider.ACTIVE_ACCOUNT_ID,
                                                         Imps.Provider.ACTIVE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME,
                                                         Imps.Provider.ACTIVE_ACCOUNT_PW,
                                                         Imps.Provider.ACTIVE_ACCOUNT_LOCKED,
                                                         Imps.Provider.ACTIVE_ACCOUNT_KEEP_SIGNED_IN,
                                                         Imps.Provider.ACCOUNT_PRESENCE_STATUS,
                                                         Imps.Provider.ACCOUNT_CONNECTION_STATUS
                                                        };
```

**But when I test it, logcat returns me this error:**

```
    01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291): query+exc+db+caught+
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291): net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: ambiguous column name: name: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT providers._id AS _id, 
providers.name AS name, providers.fullname AS fullname, providers.category AS category, accounts._id AS account_id, 
accounts.username AS account_username, accounts.pw AS account_pw, accounts.locked AS account_locked, accounts.keep_signed_in AS account_keepSignedIn, 
accountStatus.presenceStatus AS account_presenceStatus, 
accountStatus.connStatus AS account_connStatus FROM providers LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts ON (providers._id = accounts.provider AND accounts.active = 1) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN accountStatus ON (accounts._id = accountStatus.account) WHERE ((name LIKE '%%' OR fullname LIKE '%%')) ORDER BY name ASC
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1441)
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:330)
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at info.guardianproject.otr.app.im.provider.ImpsProvider.queryInternal(ImpsProvider.java:1673)
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at info.guardianproject.otr.app.im.provider.ImpsProvider.query(ImpsProvider.java:1248)
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:950)
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:210)
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:478)
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:422)
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:49)
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:35)
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:242)
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:51)
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:40)
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:123)
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I suppose that the error must be there, but I don't know why doesn't work

```
01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291): query+exc+db+caught+
    01-07 13:11:18.878: E/imProvider(8291): net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: ambiguous column name: name: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT providers._id AS _id, 
    providers.name AS name, providers.fullname AS fullname, providers.category AS category, accounts._id AS account_id, 
    accounts.username AS account_username, accounts.pw AS account_pw, accounts.locked AS account_locked, accounts.keep_signed_in AS account_keepSignedIn, 
    accountStatus.presenceStatus AS account_presenceStatus, 
    accountStatus.connStatus AS account_connStatus FROM providers LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts ON (providers._id = accounts.provider AND accounts.active = 1) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN accountStatus ON (accounts._id = accountStatus.account) WHERE ((name LIKE '%%' OR fullname LIKE '%%')) ORDER BY name ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

That renders SQL containing `WHERE (( NAME LIKE ...` and `ORDER BY NAME`

Presumably there is more than one `NAME` field so you need to fully qualify your field names so the DB knows which ones you want:

`WHERE ((providers.NAME LIKE ...`

Comment: But the projection only has 1 field called, "Name" : ' 'Imps.Provider.NAME', so I don't see where can be "duplicated" ... :S

Comment: I mean that if 2 tables had a NAME column, which one would the database use in the WHERE clause?

Comment: OK, I understand what you mean, so I suppose that the error comes from here: CursorLoader(NewChatActivity.this, Imps.Provider.CONTENT_URI_WITH_ACCOUNT,
                    ContactListFragment.PROVIDER_PROJECTION,buf == null ? null : buf.toString(),null ,Imps.Provider.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER) ?     Because I don't see where he takes the "Left Outer Join accounts" ..

Comment: The error is in the SQL string you create; `buf.append(Imps.Provider.NAME);` needs to append the full name (providers.NAME) - the same for the ORDER BY too